# Как убрать рамку для button/input?

Tags: html, css

Рылся в интернете находил много всякой информации на мою тему, но ничего из найденного не помогает. Может вы поможете.Нужно что бы из этого => [image: введите сюда описание изображения]  получилось что-то на подобие этого[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добвьте к нужному элементу

```
background: none; // убираем фон
border: none; // убирает бордер
box-shadow: none; // убираем тень, если есть
color: #fff; // текст шрифта белый
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось. Еще один вопрос, можно ли как-то сделать теперь ей отклик? Чтоб Get Started хоть как-то двигалось?

Comment: Для этого есть псевдокласы и свойства CSS